# select2 js получение клика

Tags: javascript, select2

Как правильно получить событие выбора `option` в `select2 js`?
Т.е. нажимаешь на первый `option` срабатывает одно событие; второй - второе и т.д.

```
<select id="e1">
    <option value="AL">Project first</option>
    <option value="WY">Second project</option>
    <option value="WY">Third</option>
    <option value="WY">Forth</option>   
</select>
```

js

```
$('#e1').select2();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо повесить событие на `change` на весь `select`.
Функция обработки события будет брать выбранный в данный момент элемент и запускать разные процедуры.

Примерно так:

```
$('#e1').bind({'change': function() {
    switch(this.selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
        [процедуры при выборе первого элемента из списка];
        break;
    case 1:
        [процедуры при выборе второго элемента из списка];
        break;
    [ и т.д.]
    }
}});
```

Если Вы хотите построить `switch` не по индексу, а по значению, используйте `switch($(this).val()) {`, тогда и `case "AL"` будет работать...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! При таком коде         $('#el').bind({'change': function() {
      switch(this.selectedIndex) {
      case '0':
          alert();
          break;
      }
  }});
событие не отрабатывает.

Comment: аналогично при case 'AL'

Comment: изменено... неправильно назвал Ваш id :)

Comment: )))) Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Рад. тогда с Вас галочка... закроем вопрос? поднимем статистику сайт по закрываемости :)